# How to handle ProgressBar while image is uploading to firebase

Tags: angular, progress-bar

I am uploading image to the firebase storage. But i am not able to handle the ProgressBar in my code.

### Component

```
onSubmit(){
      const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filepath)
      this.storage.upload(filepath,this.selectedImage).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
            this.upSvc.insertImageDetails(this.daydetails.value);
            this.toaster.success("Submitted successfully")
            this.router.navigate(['../Home'],{relativeTo:this.activatedroute})
          })
        }),
      ).subscribe()
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': progress + '%' }"></div>
</div>
Progress: {{progress}}% Complete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.storage.upload()` returns a `AngularFireUploadTask`.
This task has a `percentageChanges()` observable that will output what you need.

So something like

```
uploadProgress$: Observable<number>

onSubmit(){
      const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filepath)
      const task = this.storage.upload(filepath,this.selectedImage)

      this.uploadProgress$ = task.percentageChanges()

      task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
            this.upSvc.insertImageDetails(this.daydetails.value);
            this.toaster.success("Submitted successfully")
            this.router.navigate(['../Home'],{relativeTo:this.activatedroute})
          })
        }),
      ).subscribe()
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" *ngIf="uploadProgress$ | async as progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': progress + '%' }"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Through Firebase SDK**

You can catch the `state_changed` event on the node where you are uploading file and then call `snapshotChanges()` on that to get the data necessary to calculate current file upload progress.
Here is an example

```
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/rivers.jpg').put(file);

// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
  // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
  // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
  var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
  switch (snapshot.state) {
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
      console.log('Upload is paused');
      break;
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
      console.log('Upload is running');
      break;
  }
}, function(error) {
  // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function() {
  // Handle successful uploads on complete
  // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});
```

You can find more information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress)

**Through AngularFire2**

You can use the `AngularFireUploadTask` which is return by `upload()`

Then you can call `percentageChanges()` which is a `Observable` which emits the percentage of the upload progress

```
uploadProgress:Observable<number>;
uploadTask: any;
onSubmit(){
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filepath)            

  this.uploadTask = this.storage.upload(filepath,this.selectedImage).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
        this.upSvc.insertImageDetails(this.daydetails.value);
        this.toaster.success("Submitted successfully")
        this.router.navigate(['../Home'],{relativeTo:this.activatedroute})
      })
    })).subscribe()
   this.uploadProgress = this.uploadTask.percentageChanges();
    }
```

In your HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-animated" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': progress + '%' }"></div>
</div>

Progress: {{ uploadProgress | async }}% Complete
```

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#monitoring-upload-percentage)

Answer (score 0):

I had to refactor other solutions here to give me something that would work as a service:

storage.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { LogService } from './log.service';
import { Observable, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {

  uploadProgress: Observable<number>;
  uploadProgressSubscription: Subscription;
  private uploadProgressSubject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(
    private storage: AngularFireStorage,
    private logService: LogService,
  ) { }

  //private logService: LogService
    log(...data){
    this.logService.log("storage",...data);
  }

  fileToStorage = (file,basepath) => { 
    
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      this.log("file",file);
      this.log("basepath",basepath);
      const filePath = `${basepath}/${file.name}.png`;
      const storageRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
      const uploadTask = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

      uploadTask.percentageChanges()
        .subscribe((percent) => {
          this.uploadProgressSubject.next(percent);
      })

      uploadTask.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          storageRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((downloadURL) => {
            this.log("downloadURL",downloadURL);
            resolve(downloadURL);
          });
        })
      ).subscribe((task) => {},(error) => {reject(error)});
    })
  }

  uploadProgressObservable(){
    return this.uploadProgressSubject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Then in file intending track progress:

```
// init the required subscription
ngOnInit() {
    this.stepsArray = [];
    this.setImageUploadProgressSubscription()
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.imageUploadProgressSubscription.unsubscribe()
  }

  setImageUploadProgressSubscription(){
    if(!this.imageUploadProgressSubscription){
      this.imageUploadProgressSubscription = this.storageService.uploadProgressObservable()
      .subscribe((progress) => {
        this.imageProgress = progress / 100;
      })
    }
  }
```

Adding the file to storage:

```
let mainImageUrl = await this.storageService.fileToStorage(image,"Pictures");
```

HTML that handles the displaying of the progress bar

```
<div *ngIf="submitting">
  <ion-popover>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-title>
        <ion-progress-bar value="{{progress}}"></ion-progress-bar>
      </ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-content>{{progresscontent}}</ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-progress-bar value="{{imageProgress}}"></ion-progress-bar>
      </ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-popover>
</div>
```